# Change ArgumentSyntax and VariableDeclaratorSyntax to InvocationExpression

Tags: c#, string, compilation, roslyn

I have written the program below that can identify strings in both variables and parameters for methods. What I would like to do is replace these strings with a method call to a new method I'm adding to the program.

Ex:

I'm now adding this metod to the code:

```
public static string StringManipulation(string test)
{
    return test + " new value";
}
```

I would then like to replace:

```
var test = ""test var"";
```

To:

```
var test = StringManipulation(""test var"");
```

And:

```
Test(""Testing"");
```

To:

```
Test(StringManipulation(""Testing""));
```

I have found a lot of answers on how to add or replace entire nodes but in this case I wan't to reuse some values and I haven't found a good answer to this.

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
        var projectId = ProjectId.CreateNewId();
        var versionStamp = VersionStamp.Create();
        var projectInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(projectId, versionStamp, "NewProject", "projName", LanguageNames.CSharp);
        var newProject = workspace.AddProject(projectInfo);

        var sourceText = SourceText.From(
            @"using System;
              using System.Collections;
              using System.Linq;
              using System.Text;

              namespace HelloWorld
              {
                  class Program
                  {
                      static void Main(string[] args)
                      {
                          var test = ""test var"";

                          string test1 = ""test string"";

                          String test2 = ""test String"";

                          const string test3 = ""test const""; 

                          readonly string test4 = ""test readonly""; 

                          int i = 0;

                          var i2 = 0;

                          Test(""Testing"");

                          Test(""Testing"", ""Testing 2"", 1);
                      }

                      public static string Test(string test)
                      {
                          return test;
                      }

                      public static string Test(string test, string test2, int test3)
                      {
                          return test + test2 + test3;
                      }
                  }
              }");

        var document = workspace.AddDocument(newProject.Id, "NewFile.cs", sourceText);
        var syntaxRoot = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;

        var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)syntaxRoot;

        var invocationExpressions = root.DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();

        var mainNode = root.DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Identifier.ValueText == "Main"
                                                                   && x.ParameterList.Parameters.FirstOrDefault().Identifier.ValueText == "args");

        var editor = DocumentEditor.CreateAsync(document).Result;

        SeparatedSyntaxList<ParameterSyntax> parametersList = new SeparatedSyntaxList<ParameterSyntax>().AddRange
        (new ParameterSyntax[]
            {
                SyntaxFactory.Parameter(SyntaxFactory.Identifier("test")).WithType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("string")),
            }
        );

        var syntax = SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement("return test + \" new value\";");

        var newMethod = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
            SyntaxFactory.List<AttributeListSyntax>(),
            SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword), SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.StaticKeyword)),
            SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.StringKeyword)),
            null,
            SyntaxFactory.Identifier("StringManipulation"),
            null,
            SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(parametersList),
            SyntaxFactory.List<TypeParameterConstraintClauseSyntax>(),
            SyntaxFactory.Block(syntax),
            null
        );

        newMethod = newMethod.NormalizeWhitespace();

        editor.InsertAfter(mainNode, newMethod);

        foreach (var invocationExpressionSyntax in invocationExpressions)
        {
            foreach (var argument in invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList.Arguments)
            {
                if (argument.Expression.Kind() == SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Method: {invocationExpressionSyntax.Expression.GetFirstToken().Value} Parameter: {argument.Expression.GetFirstToken().Value}");
                }
            }
        }

        var localDeclaration = new LocalDeclarationVirtualizationVisitor();
        localDeclaration.Visit(root);

        var localDeclarations = localDeclaration.LocalDeclarations;

        foreach (var localDeclarationStatementSyntax in localDeclarations)
        {
            foreach (VariableDeclaratorSyntax variable in localDeclarationStatementSyntax.Declaration.Variables)
            {

                var stringKind = variable.Initializer.Value.Kind();

                if (stringKind == SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {variable.Identifier.Value} Value:{variable.Initializer.Value}");
                }
            }
        }

        var newDocument = editor.GetChangedDocument();
    }
}

class LocalDeclarationVirtualizationVisitor : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public LocalDeclarationVirtualizationVisitor()
    {
        LocalDeclarations = new List<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>();
    }

    public List<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax> LocalDeclarations { get; set; }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitLocalDeclarationStatement(LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax node)
    {
        node = (LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)base.VisitLocalDeclarationStatement(node);
        LocalDeclarations.Add(node);
        return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for modifying method calls:

```
foreach (var invocationExpressionSyntax in invocationExpressions)
{
    if (invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList.Arguments.Any(x =>
        x.Expression.Kind() == SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression))
    {

        var stringList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList.Arguments[i].Expression.Kind() == SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression)
            {
                stringList.Add("StringManipulation(\"" + invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList.Arguments[i].Expression.GetFirstToken().ValueText + "\")");
            }
            else
            {
                stringList.Add(invocationExpressionSyntax.ArgumentList.Arguments[i].Expression
                    .GetFirstToken().ValueText);
            }
        }

        SeparatedSyntaxList<ArgumentSyntax> arguments = new SeparatedSyntaxList<ArgumentSyntax>().AddRange
        (new ArgumentSyntax[]
            {
                SyntaxFactory.Argument(SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression($"{string.Join(",", stringList)}")),
            }
        );

        var newMethodWithStringObfuscation =
            SyntaxFactory
                .InvocationExpression(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(invocationExpressionSyntax.Expression
                    .GetFirstToken().ValueText))
                .WithArgumentList(
                    SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList()
                        .WithOpenParenToken(
                            SyntaxFactory.Token(
                                SyntaxKind.OpenParenToken))
                        .WithArguments(arguments)
                        .WithCloseParenToken(
                            SyntaxFactory.Token(
                                SyntaxKind.CloseParenToken)));

        Console.WriteLine($"Replacing values for method {invocationExpressionSyntax.Expression.GetFirstToken().ValueText}");

        editor.ReplaceNode(invocationExpressionSyntax, newMethodWithStringObfuscation);
    }
}
```

Code for modifying variables:

```
foreach (var localDeclarationStatementSyntax in localDeclarations)
{
    foreach (VariableDeclaratorSyntax variable in localDeclarationStatementSyntax.Declaration.Variables)
    {

        var stringKind = variable.Initializer.Value.Kind();

        if (stringKind == SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression)
        {
            var newVariable = SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement($"string {variable.Identifier.ValueText} = StringManipulation({variable.Initializer.Value});");
            newVariable.NormalizeWhitespace();

            editor.ReplaceNode(variable, newVariable);

            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {variable.Identifier.Value} Value:{variable.Initializer.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```